# Python TkInter grid issues

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I have a grid in TkInter:

```
from tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.TopFrame = Frame(root)
        self.MiddleFrame = Frame(root)
        self.BottomFrame = Frame(root)
        self.TopFrame.grid(row=0)
        self.MiddleFrame.grid(row=5)
        self.BottomFrame.grid(row=6)

        buttonQ = Button(self.BottomFrame, text="Quit", command=quit)
        buttonS = Button(self.BottomFrame, text="Save", command=self.saveToFile)
        buttonS.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
        buttonQ.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
def Function(self):
    self.grid = []
    for i in range(5):
        row = []
        for j in range(5):
            row.append(Button(self.TopFrame,width=6,height=3,command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.getClick(i, j),background='gray'))
            row[-1].grid(row=i,column=j)
        self.grid.append(row)
    row2 = []
    for k in range(4):
        row2.append(Button(self.MiddleFrame,width=6,height=3,command=lambda i=5, k=k: self.getClick(i, k),background='gray'))
        row2[-1].grid(row=6,column=k, pady=10)  

def getClick(self, i, j):
    orig_color = self.grid[i][j].cget('bg')
    if orig_color=="red":
        self.grid[i][j]["bg"]="gray"
    else:
        self.grid[i][j]["bg"]="red"

def saveToFile(self):
    myFile=open("example.txt", 'w')
    for line in range(5):
        for column in range(5):
            bg_color = self.grid[line][column].cget('bg')
            if bg_color == "red":
                myFile.write("1 ")
            else:
                myFile.write("0 ")
        myFile.write("\n")
    for column in range(4):
        bg_color2 = self.grid[5][column].cget('bg')
        if bg_color2 == "red":
            myFile.write("1 ")
        else:
            myFile.write("0 ")
    myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()
    myFile = open("example.txt",'r')
    print(myFile.read())
    myFile.close()

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.Function()
root.mainloop()
```

But the problem is that the buttons from the middle grid don't change their color on click and it returns this error:

```
line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
line 28, in <lambda>
    row2.append(Button(self.MiddleFrame,width=6,height=3,command=lambda i=5, k=k: self.getClick(i, k),background='gray'))
line 32, in getClick
    orig_color = self.grid[i][j].cget('bg')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and also when I press the `Save` button:

```
  line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)  
line 39, in saveToFile
    myFile=open("example.txt", 'w')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'example.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error, I think you need to add:

```
self.grid.append(row2)
```

In line 55 column 11 at the end of your Function function, because this adds it to your self.grid object and allows the buttons to be accessed in self.getClick.

The second error usually occurs when you have the text file open yourself. Try closing it and see if that helps

Comment: You were correct on this one. My apologies for the downvote. I cannot correct my vote however until you make an edit to your post. Maybe point out where he should place `self.grid.append(row2)` then I can update my vote :D

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I did say she should add I at the end of the function Function. However I will update the answer to be more specific, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Ya I see that... I am just off today. Don't mind me. I need a nap lol.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

After messing with your code for a few min I noticed you were missing `self.grid.append(row2)`

So fixing the indention of your methods to be inside of the class and adding `self.grid.append(row2)` after your for loop under `row2 = []` like this:

```
row2 = []
for k in range(4):
    row2.append(Button(self.MiddleFrame,width=6,height=3,command=lambda i=5, k=k: self.getClick(i, k),background='gray'))
    row2[-1].grid(row=6,column=k, pady=10)
self.grid.append(row2)
```

Works fine now. See this image:

[image]